# iis web site launch service on startup once only

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have a number of IIS 7.5 web sites hosted on various servers. I want to run a web service just once each time each site is started (not when the app pool is recycled) i.e. when the site comes up for the first time (is created) and then not to run again until the site is stopped and restarted. I had trouble Googling this because the terms cover so many things. Its the IIS equivalent of running autoexec.bat on a windows computer starting on a network (where computer maps to each hosted site). I.e. once IIS its self is up, then when each individual site starts some sort of event that can launch a further service. ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0 does not seem to answer this...

Comment: The app pool IS the process for your site. Your application is created upon the first request (or immediately if AutoStart is set), whether it is a newly created app pool or if an existing one is recycled. I don't think you can differentiate between a recycle and an initial startup.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I though.. oh dear have to find another approach